# Getting the right position in Unity

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

In OpenCV, there is a rectangle shown when something is detected.

```
Imgproc.rectangle (rgbaMat, new Point (rects [i].x, rects [i].y), new Point (rects [i].x + rects [i].width, rects [i].y + rects [i].height), new Scalar (0, 0, 255, 255), 2);
```

I want to put a 3D object or example a cube in that one corner of the rectangle.

```
myCube.transform.position = new Vector3(rects[0].x, rects[0].y);
```

The problem is that the position of the cube isnt in the rectangle but in the transform it shows the correct Vector3(float, float, float).

How can I put my cube in the position where the corner of the rectangle is?

Comment: Is one of the two Objects (rectangle or cube) a child of any parent that is scaled or translated?

Comment: @derHugo At first it was in a quad, the positions were like 0.12, 0.11 something and then I took it out of the quad and now the transform is the same as the rects[0].x, rects[0].y still the cube is not in the corner of the rectangle

Comment: @derHugo for example the rects[0].x = 196 and rects[0].y = 213, then in my cube's transform is 196, 213, 0. Yet, the cube is not in the corner of the rectangle

Comment: Screen space vs. world space.

Comment: @Draco18s i have tried Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint() but still the same

Comment: I can't debug "I tried that."

Comment: `rects[0].x = 196 and rects[0].y = 213` is this in a canvas? Canvas behave a bit different. There it depends a lot on if the canvas is set to ScreenSpace or WorldSpace... You could try to find the correct position manually by moving the cube in the scene until it is correct and than look if there is a certain pattern like e.g. cube position = rect positions / 1000; or maybe 500 etc ...

Comment: @derHugo There is a quad that is used to display the webcamtexture. Once OpenCV detects something, it displays a rectangle. The one i have given above is one of the rects starting drawing point of the rectangle. I have been searching for pattern til now. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. I wanted to place a 3d object in the center of the detected object. I asked on the OpenCV for unity forum and got a reply from the developer.

They provide a package with a solution that worked for me. [Overlay a 3D object](https://forum.unity.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/page-52#post-6746134)

In your case, you can change line 68 in DetectFace2DTo3DExample.cs to the positions of your rect.

`Matrix4x4 point3DMatrix4x4 = Get2DTo3DMatrix4x4 (new Vector2 (rects [0].x, rects [0].y), gameObject);`

[image: 3d Object Corner Placement]

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot (so I don't blame you) I've found the following which I think is what you where looking for in [this forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/page-3):

There is an [OpenCv Object detection example](https://github.com/EnoxSoftware/OpenCVObjectDetector/blob/master/Sample/ObjectDetectSample.cs).

The for you most interesting method I guess would be the most bottom one:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Results the rects to result game objects.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rects">Rects.</param>
/// <param name="color">Color.</param>
/// <param name="zPos">Z position.</param>
private void ResultRectsToResultGameObjects (IList<object> rects, Color color, float zPos)
{
    Vector3[] resultPoints = new Vector3[rects.Count];

    float textureWidth = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture.width;
    float textureHeight = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture.height;

    Matrix4x4 transCenterM = Matrix4x4.TRS (new Vector3 (-textureWidth / 2, -textureHeight / 2, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3 (1, 1, 1));

    Vector3 translation = new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x, gameObject.transform.localPosition.y, gameObject.transform.localPosition.z);
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler (gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x, gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y, gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
    Vector3 scale = new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localScale.x / textureWidth, gameObject.transform.localScale.y / textureHeight, 1);

    Matrix4x4 trans2Dto3DM = Matrix4x4.TRS (translation, rotation, scale);

    for (int i = 0; i < resultPoints.Length; i++) 
    {
        IDictionary rect = (IDictionary)rects [i];

        //get center of rect.
        resultPoints [i] = new Vector3 ((long)rect ["x"] + (long)rect ["width"] / 2, (long)rect ["y"] + (long)rect ["height"] / 2, 0);

        //translate origin to center.
        resultPoints [i] = transCenterM.MultiplyPoint3x4 (resultPoints [i]);

        //transform from 2D to 3D
        resultPoints [i] = trans2Dto3DM.MultiplyPoint3x4 (resultPoints [i]);

        //Add resultGameObject.
        GameObject result = Instantiate (resultPrefab, resultPoints [i], Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        result.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

        result.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (result.transform.localPosition.x, result.transform.localPosition.y, zPos);
        result.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        result.transform.localScale = new Vector3 ((long)rect ["width"] / textureWidth, (long)rect ["height"] / textureHeight, 20);

        result.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = color;

        resultGameObjects.Add (result);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse I didn't test that but it looks like it does what you want: place objects on the rects positions.

And ofcourse you will have to adopt it to your needs but I hope it is a good starting point for you.